# Ruby Rails Nil class on empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question I've tried getting answer to previously and it is driving me insane. Why does this not work?

undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):

```
13: <%if @myp == nil%>
14:   <%@myp = []%>
15:   <%@params = @myp%>
16: <%else%>
17:   <%@myp = [-1]%>
18:   <%@params=@myp.collect{|i| i.to_i}%>
19: <%end%>
```

It works fine in development but when I upload it  to my production server it just give me this error.

The code is from my view-file. Is there anything else I can do instead?

I think this is all relevant code regarding this function. In my controller I do have this though:

```
if params[:plates]!=nil
 @myp = params[:plates]
else
 @myp = [-1]
end
```

The only thing I am doing here is getting some info from the eventual parameters sent by the users. Sorry for the ugly coding if anyone cares.

Comment: May I ask what `@params=@myp.collect{|i| i.to_i}` is for? You might as well do `@params = @myp` instead of all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
<%if @myp == nil%>
  <%- @myp = []%>
  <%- @params = @myp%>
<%else%>
  <%- @myp = [-1]%>
  <%- @params=@myp.collect{|i| i.to_i}%>
<%end%>
```

Use `<%- %>` instead of `<% %>` in this case.

I would reconsider using `@params=@myp.collect{|i| i.to_i}` altogether. It's not needed. You can achieve the same thing with `@params = @myp`

Comment: What does `<%-` do versus just `<%`?

Comment: Thanks, the <%- did not work but your other suggestion did. Thanks a lot!